# File.Exists can't find the file

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDown
    If Not ListBox1.SelectedItem = "" Then


        Timer1.Stop()

        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
            ContextMenuStrip1.Show(MousePosition)
            ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y)
            selt = ListBox1.SelectedItem
            apksv = (Adb("/c adb shell pm path " + selt)).Replace("package:", "")
            Dim spl As String() = apksv.Split("/"c)
            For Each s As String In spl
                tempout.Text = s
            Next
            apkl = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\adb\" + tempout.Text

            
        End If
    End If
    Timer1.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Timer1.Stop()

    Finalout.Text = Adb("/c adb pull " + apksv)

    With FolderBrowserDialog1
        If .ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then


            If File.Exists(apkl) Then         
                File.Move(apkl, .SelectedPath + "\" + tempout.Text)   
            Else
                Finalout.Text = "Not moved " + apkl
            End If

        End If

    End With
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

End Class

File.Exists(apkl) Not working i cant find a solution

Comment: It's rather unlikely, that `File.Exists` doesn't work. Have you tried setting a breakpoint, inspecting the value of `apkl` and checking in the explorer if that file really exists? Maybe your value contains some additional whitespaces

Comment: Never use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, you don't know what might be *current*, especially if you use FileDialogs of any kind. You have a WinForms app there, if you want to read the current starting directory, use `Application.StartupPath` -- Also, use `Path.Combine()` to build paths, not simple (brittle) string concatenation.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "Not working"?